# PL/SQL: How do I declare session variables?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I declare a session variable in PL/SQL - one that will persist for the duration of the session only, without me having to store it in the database itself?

Answer (score 15):

You can use a 'user-created context' to store data shared across multiple units within a session.

First, create a context:

```
CREATE CONTEXT SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'current_schema')|| '_ctx' USING PKG_COMMON
```

Second, create a package that would manage your context:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_COMMON
IS
   common_ctx_name   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (60)
                 := SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'current_schema')
                    || '_ctx';

   FUNCTION fcn_get_context_name RETURN VARCHAR2;
   PROCEDURE prc_set_context_value (var_name VARCHAR2, var_value NUMBER);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_COMMON
IS
   FUNCTION fcn_get_context_name
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN common_ctx_name;
   END;

   PROCEDURE prc_set_context_value (var_name VARCHAR2, var_value NUMBER)
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_SESSION.set_context (common_ctx_name, var_name, var_value);
   END;
END;
```

The prc_set_context_value can be more advanced, that's just an example.
With the context and the package created you can start using them.
Set a context variable using a procedure call

```
begin
  PKG_COMMON.prc_set_context_value('MyVariable', 9000)
end;
```

and use it anywhere - any procedure, package, function or event a view.

```
CREATE VIEW V_TEST AS
  SELECT ID, LOGIN, NAME 
    FROM USERS 
   WHERE ROLE_ID =  SYS_CONTEXT(PKG_COMMON.FCN_GET_CONTEXT_NAME, 'MyVariable')
```

For more information see http://www.psoug.org/reference/sys_context.html

Comment: When I create context it says: ORA-28265: NameSpace beginning with 'sys_' is not allowed.

 I tried to set it into variable. But it sets variable name instead of value

Comment: Why dynamically build up the context name using `CURRENT_SCHEMA`? Does it need to be globally unique or something?

Answer (score 14):

You create a package level variable.  This is a minimal example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package
AS
    FUNCTION get_a RETURN NUMBER;
END my_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package
AS
    a  NUMBER(20);

    FUNCTION get_a
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN a;
    END get_a;
END my_package;
/
```

If you do this you should read up on (and handle correctly) `ORA-04068` errors.  Each database session will have it's own value for a.  You can try this with:

```
SELECT my_package.get_a FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you need a procedure to *set* the value?

Comment: @jpmc26 It would be normal to have a setter.  I think you can put the variable in the package (not the package body) to make it public.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a **short, but intuitive syntax** and thus would create e.g. some **`ctx` package** that just provides **one function to set and get some global "variables"**.
(valid for the current session only ; in my case no need to implement it as user-created-context variables, but easily changeable to it under the hood ; example with some `foo varchar2` and `bar number` vars)

**usage**:

```
select ctx.foo from dual                                                 -- => null (init)
select ctx.foo('a') from dual                                            -- => 'a'
select ctx.foo('b') from dual ; select ctx.foo from dual                 -- => 'b', 'b'
```

.

```
-- (optimizer should cause the subquerys unselected columns not to be executed:)
select 'ups' from (select ctx.foo('a') from dual) ; select ctx.foo from dual   -- => null

select ctx.bar(1.5) from dual ; select ctx.bar from dual                 -- => 1.5,  1.5
-- ...
```

**package header**:

```
create or replace package  ctx  as

  -- select ctx.foo from dual                                            -- => null (init)
  -- select ctx.foo('a') from dual                                       -- => 'a'
  -- select ctx.foo('b') from dual ; select ctx.foo from dual            -- => 'b', 'b'
  -- (optimizer should cause the subquerys unselected columns not to be executed:)
  -- select 'ups' from (select ctx.foo('a') from dual) ; select ctx.foo from dual
    -- => null
  -- parallel_enable for queries since it should not change inside of them
  function foo(  set varchar2 := null  ) return varchar2  parallel_enable;

  -- (samples like in foo above as executable test comments like in foo above skipped for 
  -- brevity)
  function bar(  set number := null  ) return  number  parallel_enable;

end;
```

**package body**:

```
create or replace package body  ctx  as

  foo_  varchar2(30);  -- e.g. 'blabla'
  bar_  number;


  -- internal helper function for varchars
  function set_if_not_null( ref  in out  varchar2,  val  varchar2  ) return varchar2 as 
  begin
    if  val is not null  then  ref := val;  end if;
    return ref ;
  end;


  -- internal helper function for numbers
  function set_if_not_null( ref  in out  number,  val number  ) return  number  as begin
    if  val is not null  then  ref := val;  end if;
    return ref ;
  end;


  -- (same test comments like in foo above skipped for brevity)      
  function foo(  set varchar2 := null  ) return varchar2  parallel_enable as begin
    return set_if_not_null(  foo_,  set  ) ;
  end;


  -- (same test comments like in foo above skipped for brevity)      
  function bar(  set number := null  ) return  number  parallel_enable as begin
    return set_if_not_null(  bar_,  set  ) ;
  end;

end;
```

If you know that the **variable (`foo`) may change within a single query then remove `parallel_enable`**, which should otherwise be more performant if queries are parallelizable.

Depending on ones needs one could of course add some `foo_reset()` to set it to null etc..